# Not able to add two variables in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I am new to Jquery. I want to add two variables. Both are gloable variables.
Please see the "Add the variables" in the end of this code. The "cashupfirst" variable displays the value corectly but the "cashupsecond" variable says "undefined". But I can display the correct value of "cashupsecond" before this code.  Please help.

```
 jQuery(function($) {

  var cashupfirst, cashupsecond;
  var a, parent, input, doneLink, b, i, eq, c, z;
  $(".Cashups").delegate("td:eq(3) > a", "click", function(event) {

    //Index reading(not used here)
    //var eq = $(this).parent().children("a").index(this);


    // The `a` has been clicked; cancel the action as
    // we're handling it
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    // Remember it and its parent
    a = $(this);
    parent = a.parent();

    // Insert an input in front of it, along with a done link
    // because blur can be problematic
    input = $("<input type='text' size='10'>");
    input.insertBefore(a);
    input.blur(doneHandler);
    doneLink = $("<a href='#'>done</a>");
    doneLink.insertBefore(a);
    doneLink.click(doneHandler);

    // Put the text of the link in the input
    input.val(a.text());


    // Temporarily detach the link from the DOM to get it
    // out of the way
    a.detach();

    // Give the input focus, then wait for it to blur
    input[0].focus();

    // Our "done" handler
    function doneHandler() {
      // Replace the content of the original link with
      // the updated content
      a.text(input.val());

      cashupfirst = a.text();
      alert(cashupfirst);
      //Set cookie to pass the text value to update it to table permanently
      $.cookie('demoCookie',cashupfirst,{expires: 7, path: '/'});       

      // Put the link back, remove our input and other link
      a.insertBefore(input);
      input.remove();
      doneLink.remove();

      }     

  }); 



  $(".Cashups").delegate("td:eq(9) > a", "click", function(event) {

    // The `a` has been clicked; cancel the action as
    // we're handling it
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    // Remember it and its parent
    a = $(this);
    parent = a.parent();

    // Insert an input in front of it, along with a done link
    // because blur can be problematic
    input = $("<input type='text' size='10'>");
    input.insertBefore(a);
    input.blur(doneHandler);
    doneLink = $("<a href='#'>done</a>");
    doneLink.insertBefore(a);
    doneLink.click(doneHandler);

    // Put the text of the link in the input
    input.val(a.text());


    // Temporarily detach the link from the DOM to get it
    // out of the way
    a.detach();

    // Give the input focus, then wait for it to blur
    input[0].focus();

    // Our "done" handler
    function doneHandler() {
      // Replace the content of the original link with
      // the updated content
      a.text(input.val());      
      cashupsecond = a.text();
      alert(cashupsecond);

      //Set cookie to pass the text value to update it to table permanently
       $.cookie('demoCookie1',cashupsecond,{expires: 7, path: '/'});


      // Put the link back, remove our input and other link
      a.insertBefore(input);
      input.remove();
      doneLink.remove();

    }

    //Add the variables

            if  (cashupfirst!= '' && cashupsecond!= '') {
        alert(cashupfirst);
                alert(cashupsecond);
        var xyz = (parseInt(cashupfirst) + parseInt(cashupfirst));
            jQuery('td#cashcalculator_total a').html(xyz);
    } 

  }); 
  //alert(cashupsecond);


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var xyz = parseInt(cashupfirst) + parseInt(cashupsecond);
```

The `alert` function does not return what has been alerted.

EDIT:

Okay, I see what's wrong. You must move the adding of the variables to inside the second doneHandler function, otherwise it won't wait until you have received a value for cashupsecond:

```
// Our "done" handler
function doneHandler() {
    ...

    //Add the variables
    if  (cashupfirst!= '' && cashupsecond!= '') {
        alert(cashupfirst);
        alert(cashupsecond);
        var xyz = parseInt(cashupfirst) + parseInt(cashupsecond);
        jQuery('td#cashcalculator_total a').html(xyz);
    }
}

// Don't add the variables here.
```

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. The problem is cashupsecond is undefined. I am not sure why. Thanks.